# How to compile lesscss using node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line, compiler-construction, less

Hi,
I have finished to code my website using `lesscss` client side and now want to compile `less` so I have donwloaded `node.js`. My website is running on localhost and I want first to know:

1. where I have to install node.js
2. what I have to do next ( commands lines tools, commands lines etc. ).

If someone can help me because I'm a newbie in this field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install the LESS compiler directly from `npm`.

1. Install `node.js`. Go to [this page](http://nodejs.org/download/) and download the installer for your platform.
   If you're on Windows, download the `.msi`; if you are on OSX, download the `.pkg` file. Whenever possible, download the 64-bit version (unless your system is running only 32-bit hardware and software). If you are on Linux and you want to use package managers, see [this page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint).
2. Once you have `node.js` installed, you should also have `npm`, which is *`node.js` Package Manager*. You can open a terminal/console and run `npm -v` to make sure everything is installed correctly.
3. Eventually, you can install the LESS compiler by simply executing:

   ```
   npm install -g less
   ```

(note: on OSX and Linux you may need to run this with sudo: `sudo npm install -g less`).

The LESS compiler will then be available as the `lessc` command. See [examples here](http://lesscss.org/#using-less).

PS: Some GUIs also exist for simplifying working with `lessc`. Google "less gui windows/mac/linux" to see many results, like [this one for Mac](http://incident57.com/less/).

Comment: In node.js website is possible to download both .exe or .msi package for Windows, but .exe seems to simply open a command prompt shell. What is difference between two packages, and how to choose between them? I did not find this answer anywhere.

Comment: @LucaDetomi you should ask a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

it's not mentioned what to do after installing node.js and installing less compiler on your node.

Go to your folder where you are hosting your project locally and then type styles. less styles.css. This should initiate the conversion from less to CSS at the node command prompt.

Comment: I think you meant to say type, `lessc styles.less styles.css` where "styles.less" is the less file you have edited and "styles.css" is the compiled css.