# Editing less files in Joomla

Tags: joomla, less

I'm beginner in Joomla So please any one help me. I'm editing on less files in both locations (media/guild/less/ and templates//less/) but changes are not reflected in front-end. Why has not reflected changes in the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your less files are not compiled to css, so no changes appear. Less can be compiled in the browser using Javascript, or via the commandline. I my opinion, there are only very few cases, in which it makes sense to compile in the browser.

To compile those files from the commandline you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976849/how-to-compile-lesscss-using-node-js)

If you are new to Less/npm and all other needed stuff, you should have a look at the [official docs](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: But can you explain why is not compile auto

Comment: Well no, should it? If yes, are the needed dependencies to compile less installed?

Answer (score 0):

As @philipp points out, Less files need to be compiled before they can be used.

Templates that use Less handle this in different ways. For example, Less files might be recompiled and saved each time you save the template settings. Deleting the Joomla cache and refreshing the front-end of the website might also trigger a recompile of the Less files.

For simple and future proof changes, it is often easier to [override the CSS via a custom CSS file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120) compared to editing the Less files directly.